# Filtering LIstview that extends LIst Activity

Tags: android, listview, filter

I've been reading some topics about filtering a list-view, but i am getting confused because i only got o few knowledge on adapters and different kinds of it. i found a solution thats is almost similar to my problem. Here is the code posted by Zoleas

```
TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            _myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    };
    _filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    _filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

I am confused on how i can declare my adapter in the method Ontextchanged because my adapter looks like this.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result));
```

Need help on how to implement the filter here is my full code on my listview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstaid);
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.acET);
        DbHelper tblFa = new DbHelper(this);
    tblFa.open();
    ArrayList<String> result = tblFa.getFAData();
    result = tblFa.getFAData();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    tblFa.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that;

```
EditText edt = (EditText) this.view.findViewById(R.id.editTxtView);

        edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourListviewID);


                YourAdapterOrWhateverAdapter adapter = (YourAdapterOrWhateverAdapter) listView.getAdapter();  


               adapter.getFilter().filter(s);



        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
```

Comment: Yikes! There is no need to use `findViewById()` twice every time a letter is added to or removed from the EditText. And why do you use `setAdapter()` to pass the ListView its current adapter? (Sorry, but leenolasco's code is faster than this suggestion.)

Comment: yeap i checked again, you r right. findViewById() and setAdapter() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to create another field variable, just like `filterText`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> _myAdapter;
```

And use it in `onCreate()` like this:

```
_myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
setListAdapter(_myAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks sir its now working!! how do i make this search a letter that is in between the word?

Comment: "how do i make this search a letter that is in between the word?" I don't understand. Could you give me an example?

Comment: if i press "A" the list would return all words starting with letter A. what i am asking for sir is when a press A it would return words with that contains the character sequence even if it is between the words. sample if i press A,L it would return the words with a and L with it respectively

Comment: So if you press "al" you expect to see words like "Aloof", "Bald", "Canal", etc.?